# Opposite of particle decay

Tags: particle-physics

I have read about [particle decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay), a process in which one particle becomes several other particles. However, I have not been able to find much information about its opposite: several particles combining into one particle. Is such a process possible, and if so, under what conditions? For example, a free neutron may decay into a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino. Could a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino somehow be joined into a neutron?

Edit: Everyone, thank you for your help, but let me try to make what I'm looking for clearer. I want to know whether several particles can join into ONE particle, in an exact reverse of that one particle decaying into several particles. As far as I know, I don't think an atomic nucleus counts as one particle. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Particle combining takes place in stars every time. The most effective producers of elements are exploding stars including Black holes.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler True, but successful proton-proton fusion has a very low probability. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction#The_proton-proton_chain_reaction) says "The half-life of a proton in the core of the Sun before it is involved in a successful proton-proton fusion is estimated to be about one billion years, even at the extreme pressures and temperatures found there." This is actually rather fortunate: if the probability were higher, stars would consume their fuel faster, and die sooner.

Answer (score 26):

Even if the reaction is not prohibited by energy/momentum or other conservation laws, it would have a tiny cross section: shooting one kind of particle at a target is easy, but shooting two at the same time, not so much (particularly if one is an antineutrino). However there is such a thing as [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture) by a proton in the nucleus, producing a neutron and an electron neutrino: $p + e^- \rightarrow n + \nu_e$.

Comment: And so-called "inverse beta-decay" which is not what the OP asked about, but $\bar{\nu}_e + p \to n + e^+$, which is used as a tool in reactor neutrino experiments.

Comment: You don't have to shoot a nutrino at the other two particles — given the two, it can conjur a  nutrino pair from the vacuum.  That's why you get a nutrino out rather than shooting an antinutrino in.

Comment: Cross-sections aren't well-defined for 2->1 processes.

Comment: You don't have enough phase-space to integrate over the Dirac for energy-momentum conservation,  you have $\delta^4 (p_i -p_f) d^3 p$

Comment: I think an intuitive version of what @innisfree is saying is that the decay happens in the rest frame of the decaying particle, with the outgoing particles' momenta perfectly balancing and their energy exactly adding up to the mass of the decayer. Finding the same set of particles somewhere with exactly the required momenta for that perfect balance to create a perfectly on-shell single particle is vanishingly unlikely. If you have 2 or more particles in the final state, they can absorb some imperfection into their relative momenta, but that's not the inverse of an unprompted decay.

Comment: @andy 'finding the same set of particles somewhere with exactly the required momenta for that perfect balance to create a perfectly on-shell single particle is vanishingly unlikely.' I don't agree with that. E.g. $\sigma (pp \to h) $ is nonvanishing. You kill the remaining delta-function with an integral overs pdfs. Whether it's likely/unlikely/vanishingly unlikely depends on distribution of momenta of initial state.

Comment: Sure, I agree: that gives you a continuous distribution to integrate over, and hence get rid of your delta functions. I was just rephrasing your statement about 2->1 not being well-defined without phase-space integrals. PDFs (and the constrained situation of 2 incoming hadrons in a head-on collision) are taking us further away from the reverse of a decay, though.

Comment: Something I'd not thought about before: are 2->1 processes still undefined with ep collisions, where there's only one PDF to integrate over? There's still only a single configuration, i.e. zero phase-space volume, that satisfies on-shell constraints... I guess a delta remains unintegrated?

Comment: @innisfree Even if the term "cross-section" in the strict sense doesn't apply to $2 \to 1$ processes, it's still true that such processes have "tiny cross-sections" in the more colloquial sense that "you don't have a whole lot of wiggle room to get what you want to happen." I think the phrase does clarify that phase-space is a major limitation, in a way that might help the OP understand the answer to their question. But I agree that it's a good clarification to point out that we are slightly abusing terminology.

Comment: @innisfree I followed up on your comments with a new question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499947/92058, in case you'd like to answer it.

Answer (score 13):

As Nick says, in laboratory conditions the crossections are very very small. In a way two body  [resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonances_in_scattering_from_potentials) are the only reversible example with high probability to study in the laboratory.

In the grand cosmological laboratory of the universe, in [its history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe)  at the [hadron epoch:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron_epoch)

> In physical cosmology, the hadron epoch was the period in the evolution of the early universe during which the mass of the universe was dominated by hadrons. It started approximately 10<sup>-6</sup> seconds after the Big Bang, when the temperature of the universe had fallen sufficiently to allow the quarks from the preceding quark epoch to bind together into hadron

In this model  the inverse processes exist , due to the very high average energies of the quarks and gluons the crossections for generating protons and neutrons out of three quarks is high and reversible, until the universe cools enough that quarks are no longer asymptotically free. So there is a three to one process.

Comment: Lol, only a physicist would call a millionth of a second "an epoch" :)

Comment: Cross-sections aren't well-defined for 2->1 processes.

Comment: @innisfree counterexample e+e-  --> Z

Comment: $\sigma (ee\to Z) $ isn't well defined. I don't see how just saying it is a counter-example. You don't have enough phase space integrals (you have 3) to integrate 4 Dirac deltas.

Comment: Now, you can have a distribution of initial state momenta, e.g. parton distribution function for quarks, and integrate over that distribution to kill the remaining delta.

Comment: @innisfree  I am an experimentalist who believes what peer reviewed theories say, at least trust the honest intention . The particle data group is  one of the sources I trust . Look at page 5 of this http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-cross-section-formulae.pdf .

Comment: p5 shows $\sigma (f \bar f \to Z \to f \bar f)$? 2-> 2?

Comment: A resonance which is Z, look at the plot again page 5 here http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf . I see that as two input, one for a delta(t)  output which I measure.

Comment: Ok, that link on p5 shows cross sections for ee to hadrons, again 2-> many, not 2-> 1.

Comment: I agree with @innisfree: there's zero phase-space volume for e+e- -> stable Z. But the fact that it's a resonance (with a width), and that initial-state radiation can "return" off-resonance e+e- beams to the peak means that e.g. LEP beams didn't need to be tuned to the Z mass with *perfect* accuracy.

Answer (score 12):

The [triple-alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process) is a way $C^{12}$ is formed in stars from three $He^4$ nuclei once (most of) the hydrogen in the core has been burned.  It is really two reactions,
$He^4+He^4 \to Be^8, Be^8+He^4 \to C^{12}.$
$  Be^8$ is unstable, but lasts long enough for this to happen if the helium is dense and hot enough.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, and way more!**

*Every* process (we know so far) is CPT-invariant. This stands for Charge (so the charge of the particle, if it is a particle/anti-particle), Parity (in which direction it rotates, a little bit like left-/right-handedness or chirality) and Time (so forward/backward in time, if a decay is forward -> the recombination, what you asked for, is backward; or vice-versa). Invariant means that if you invert all of those quantities simultaneously, your process is still the same, e.g. can still happen.

Or in other words, for every decay, there exists a recombination of the same particles (only with every charge and parity inverted).

This happens all the time. Otherwise, no heavier particles would even exist! But it is way more difficult do achieve it artificially because all particles have to hit one spot at the same time. But, for example inside the sun, this is quite "common".

Comment: I actually was thinking about this angle, because I heard that the fundamental laws of physics are time-reversible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reverse of the "particle decay" process is possible.  The proof of this is the existence of the universe (and us in it).  If it were not possible, there would not be molecules, elements, compounds, etc..  The best example of this, is hydrogen (the most abundant element), which is formed by "uniting" protons and electrons,etc..  The conditions required, obviously, are the ones that existed right after the Big Bang.

The reason there is more "literature" on the decay process, is that it is **a lot easier** and **less expensive** to observe and measure the decay processes, than to combine particles. It takes a lot of energy and money to perform the combination process.